# WPF Prism application does not Shutdown

Tags: wpf, prism-4

I wrote the simplest possible WPF Prism application. It does not shutdown.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="PrismApp.Desktop.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Shell.xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace PrismApp.Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
namespace PrismApp.Desktop
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            var shell = new Shell();
            return shell;
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        }
    }
}
```

**Shell.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PrismApp.Desktop.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Shell" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: just remove the StartupUri="Shell.xaml" from the App.xaml and see what is happening?. Still you are not allowing the bootstrapper to load your Shell and insteard StartupUri is over taking.

Comment: The startup Uri is your problem.

Theck out this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114956/prism-app-does-not-exit-when-closed/11987246#11987246

Answer (score 0):

i just had a look through my prism project and the setup is slightly different.  maybe it will help

in the app.xaml, i do **NOT** have

```
StartupUri="Shell.xaml"
ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
```

then in app.xaml.cs i have the following

```
private void StartupContainer()
{
   Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
   bootstrapper.Run();
   bootstrapper.ShowDefaultView();
}
```

and in my bootstrapper.cs

```
Shell _shell;

protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    _shell = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    return _shell;
}

public void ShowDefaultView()
{
    _shell.Show();
}
```

where Shell is my WPF window

Comment: You do realize you don't have to define your own `Shell` field because the `Bootstrapper` already provides a Shell property. Also, instead of ShowDefaultView you should override `InitializeShell`.